# What is "segmentation fault: 11"? (Mac os x GCC assembly run-time error)

Tags: macos, gcc, assembly, runtime-error, x86-64

This code assembles fine using GCC in terminal:

```
.globl _sub
_sub:
    push %rbp
    mov %rbp,%rsp
    mov $0xBEEF,%eax
    pop %rbp
    ret

.globl _main

_main:
    push %rbp
    mov %rbp,%rsp
    call _sub
    mov $0,%eax
    pop %rbp
    ret
```

But when I run the a.out file, I get this error:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

If I run it in GDB this is the error I get:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000001
0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
```

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mov %rbp, %rsp` corrupts the stack pointer. You probably want `mov %rsp, %rbp` instead.

Due to historical reasons, some assemblers consider operands to be left-to-right while others take them right-to-left.

Answer (score 1):

You get segmentation fault because you write the value of `rbp` to `rsp`, although you should be doing the opposite:

```
push %rbp
mov %rbp,%rsp
```

This can be fixed easily:

```
push %rbp
mov %rsp,%rbp
```